# Express - Asynchronous commit to DB using bcrypt

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I am running the below code within a transaction:

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { email, name, password } = req.body;
    //insert syntax
    //When sending back response on an error from a server never send information back as error, instead send just a message
    dbConnection.transaction((trx) => {
        return trx.insert({
            name: name,
            emailaddress: email,
            createddt: new Date()
        }).into('users')
        .returning('emailaddress')
        .then((response) => {
            bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
            console.log(response);
            dbConnection('login').insert({
            emailaddress: response,
            password: hash
            })
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err))
    })
    })
})
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Practice\React\sign-in-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Practice\React\sign-in-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Practice\React\sign-in-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at dbConnection.transaction.then.catch.err (C:\Practice\React\sign-in-api\server.js:67:32)
    at tryCatcher (C:\Practice\React\sign-in-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Practice\React\sign-in-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Practice\React\sign-in-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Practice\React\sign-in-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Practice\React\sign-in-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:689:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\Practice\React\sign-in-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Practice\React\sign-in-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Practice\React\sign-in-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
```

Few questions:

1. Is it a good idea to make an asynchronous call while saving to DB? In this case bcrypt is the async call.
2. Is there a better way to write the below?

Any responses are appreciated.

Comment: The error means that you're already in the body or finished state. Try to look for anything that had send a header after some of the body has already been written. Look for callbacks that are accidentally called twice, or any error that happens after the body is sent. I think your catch was executed setting the res object , later inside bcrypt error was raised but req object headers were already executed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After some thought used a settimeout on the bcrypt which did the trick.